# The stay in blackjack python code doesnt work

Tags: python

There isnt a error in the code but when I run the code it doesn't do it the way I want it to

```
elif player == '-blackjack':
    betted = int(input('how much would you like to gamble?  :   '))
    your_card = random.randrange(2,21)
    your_drawed = random.randrange(1,12)
    opponent_card = random.randrange(2,21)
    opponent_drawed = random.randrange(1,12)

    if betted > player_money:
        print('oye you dont have this much')
        pass
    elif betted <= player_money:
        game = True
        while game:
            opponent_drawed = random.randrange(1,12)
            your_drawed = random.randrange(1,12)
            print(' ________________________________')
            print('|Your total card : ' + str(your_card))
            print('|Opponents total card : ?')
            print('|h to hit, s to stay.')
            player = input('|________________________________')
            if opponent_card < 15:
                opponent_card += opponent_drawed
            elif opponent_card >= 15:
                pass
            if player == 'h':
                your_card = your_card + your_drawed
                if your_card > 21:
                    if opponent_card > 21:
                        print('BOTH BUSTED! tie')
                        game = False
                    elif opponent_card <= 21:
                        print('BUSTED! You lost ' + str(betted))
                        player_money -= betted
                        game = False
                elif your_card == 21:
                    if opponent_card == 21:
                        print('Both 21! Tie')
                        game = False
                    elif opponent_card < 21 or opponent_card > 21:
                        print('You win! you won ' + str(betted))
                        player_money += betted
                        game = False
                elif opponent_card > 21:
                    if your_card > 21:
                        print('man opponent busted tho, you should have stayed TIE!')
                        game = False
                    elif your_card <= 21:
                        print('opponent busted! you won ' + str(betted))
                        player_money += betted
                        game = False
            elif player == 's':
                if opponent_card == 21:
                    if your_card == 21:
                        print('both 21! tie!')
                        game = False
                    elif your_card < 21:
                        print('opponent reached 21 in this turn you lose ' + str(betted))
                        player_money -= betted
                        game = False
                elif opponent_card > 21:
                    print('opponent busted you win ' + str(betted))
                    player_money += betted
                    game = False
```

When I run this code, the hit for blackjack works but the 's' button stay doesn't work
[image]

this happens when I try to stay, why does it do this? When I do hit it does successfully go up and everything works fine but just the stay part doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

You need another conditional for the case where `opponent_card < 21`.

Comment: The entire block under `elif player == 's'` has two conditions. One tests whether `opponent_card == 21`, and the other tests whether `opponent_card > 21`. You need to include the third possibility.